# How to display a snackbar AFTER a function finishes executing?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, async-await

I have an ElevatedButton. When pressed, it calls a function to download certain files from Firebase Storage.

**ElevatedButton**

```
ElevatedButton(
 onPressed: () {
  await downloadProductsList();  // function to download files from firebase
  
  final snackbar = SnackBar(content: Text('Download complete!'), duration: Duration(seconds: 2));
  
  setState() {
   ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackbar);
  }})
```

**downloadProductsList Function**

```
  downloadProductsList() async {
    final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
    final customers = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
    final baseDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = "${baseDir.path}/assets";

    for (int i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
      final filePath = "$path/${customers[i]}.csv";
      final file = await File(filePath).create(recursive: true);

      final fileRef = storageRef.child("assets/${customers[i]}.csv");
      fileRef
          .writeToFile(file)
          .whenComplete(() => print('downloaded ${customers[i]}.csv'));
    }
  }
```

The issue I'm facing is that the SnackBar displays as soon as the button is pressed. Not after the downloads have been completed.

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the function downloadProductsList async and write await with this here it will wait for the function to complete and then the SnackBar will be shown.

Comment: I made the downloadProductsList function async and called it like this :`await downloadProductsList ();` It still displays the snackbar immediately after button click

Comment: can you show me the downloadProductsList Function

Comment: I have added the code to the original post

Comment: add Future<void> at the start of the function downloadProductsList where you are declaring it and make the onPressed function async and add await before calling the downloadProductsList function

Comment: Still the same. It shows up as soon as I press the button. I even rebuilt the app to be sure

Comment: add await also at the start of fileRef.writeToFile(file) if it is future